# Which React Hooks can be defined anonymously?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, anonymous-function

In order to avoid unnecessary renders, for brevity can [*Memoize hooks*](https://www.codebeast.dev/react-memoize-hooks-useRef-useCallback-useMemo/) be defined anonymously?:

```js
<button onClick=useCallback(() => {activateLasers(deps)}, deps)>
  Activate Lasers
</button>
```

Would `button` still re-render as intended; Only when `deps` (`props` controlled by parent) change?

And can `useRef`, `useMemo` be defined anonymously and still memoize properly as well?

Comment: i think it will work but the code will look ugly

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if I got well the question but if you mean that deps is a props that will be changed by the parent, unless you handle that in useEffect or useMemo the button will render again every time that deps change.